# Safari renders › as ÔÇ║

Tags: encoding, safari, character-encoding

On my CSS I have something like

```
.btn:after {
    content: "›";
}
```

...which is basically appending `›` to the end of the label of all buttons.

It works on most browsers but in Safari the little chevron is rendered as `ÔÇ║`.

It's obvious that it is some encoding problem but it's hard to search the web for that particular situation.

`<meta charset="utf-8">` is included in the `<head>` as usual.

Any ideas?

Comment: File saved as utf-8?

Comment: the CSS file has @charset "UTF-8"; at the top if that's what you mean...

Comment: I mean is it saved as utf-8 as opposed to ansi? (file > save as > encoding) or whatever

Comment: sorry - so the CSS file is UTF-8 and the HTML file is UTF-8 BOM. I checked on ST3 console with `view.encoding()`